# Sphinx reStructuredText show an image next to a hyperlink

Tags: image, hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In a Sphinx RST documentation, I am trying to put an image next to a hyperlink.
Similar to this image here:

[image: image 1]

I have tried a good amount of combinations and different options for

```
`Text <https://hyper.link>`_
```

and

```
.. image:: https://image.url
```

Searching the reStructuredText documentation didn't help me either.
In theory I can use HTML inside this documentation file, but do now have any knowledge in that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [substitution](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions) to replace `|foo|` with an image.

```
- `Deutsch <https://german.org/>`_ |tag|
- `French <https://french.org/>`_ |tag|

.. |tag| image:: https://image.url
```

Comment: When I try to do that, it adds the image to the next line, rather than next to the hyperlink. Did you try that? Maybe this doesn't work for me because we still use Sphinx version 2.4.4, but also have a slightly modified version of the sphinx_rtd_theme theme.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. For some themes, you might need to modify CSS so that the image has a `float: left` or similar.

Comment: The problem was the "display: block;" css property which was inside the custom.css
Thank you very much for your help.